# Set constraint based on another's cell value

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, constraints, generated-columns

I am making a text based RPG and I want to add a class to the player's stats, let's say for example Warrior or Hunter, I decided to use sqlite3 to store the data and I want it to assign a default value to the Power stat based on Class stat.
This is not the code but what i want it to do:

```
if Class is Hunter:
 Power = 3
elif Class is Warrior:
 Power = 5
```

Comment: have you looked into using dictionaries for this? for example, a `dict` mapping class type to power to assign to each one.

Comment: I want to set the constraint within the database, when I define the collumn Power, make it take a default value based on Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+ you can define the column `power` as a [`GENERATED`](https://sqlite.org/gencol.html) column:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  class TEXT,
  power INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE class WHEN 'Hunter' THEN 3 WHEN 'Warrior' THEN 5 END)
);
```